# HAML - Form styling and tricks - new from plain static pages

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, haml, styling

I am trying to get my form field styling down for my page but I am having some problems figuring out how to work with haml.  I could just switch back to html css and such but what is the fun in that.

I have a form that I am trying to style so I have a box for a submitting and a submit button inline. I keep getting all sorts of goofy layouts with this.

Comment: I think you can add <br> tag before the submit button

Comment: Please don't post questions that depend on external links to be answerable. Your code needs to go in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I see is that you (or HAML) is adding a `<br />` tag at the wrong place (see code below). The `<br />` is *after* the `<label>` but it should be after the `<input>`. In that way, the next label and field will go onto the next line.

```
<label for="user_username">Username</label>
<br />
<input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="user[username]" id="user_username" />

<label for="user_email">Email</label>
<br />
<input type="email" name="user[email]" id="user_email" />

<label for="user_password">Password</label>
<br />
<input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" />
```

See this updated code below for correct alignment:

```html
    <label for="user_username">Username</label>
    <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="user[username]" id="user_username" /><br />
    
    <label for="user_email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="user[email]" id="user_email" /><br />
    
    <label for="user_password">Password</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" /><br />
```

This is valid code in HAML (hence the `%br` to go to the next line):

```
%label{:for=>"name", } Name:
%input{:id=>"name", :type=>"text", :required => true}
%br
%label{:for=>"email", } Email address:
%input{:id=>"email", :type=>"email", :required => true}
```

See the [example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyepNo) rendered.